# How to use CCDirector and other changes in COCOS2D 3.0?

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have to convert my game into new version of cocos2dx.

I have finished to conversion but got deprecated the followings.

```
 COCOS2DX-2.X                            COCOS2DX-3.X

 sharedDirector()->getWinSize()              -> ?

 SpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()  -> ?

  glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, glVertices);

 kCCVertexAttrib_Position                    -> ?
```

Can any one assist me to convert?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solutions

```
 Size screenSize =  Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();   - No need sharedDirector()

 SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("example.plist"); - No need sharedSpriteFrameCache
 glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);   - No need kCCVertexAttrib_Position
```

This will help for your conversion.

Comment: Can I get some solution in Objective C - Cocos2d v3 as well? I don't have 'GLProgram' class in Cocos2d V3.